# append column values to row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = ('y','y','y')
df['col2'] = ('a','b','c')
df['col3'] = ('x','x','x')
print df
```

I have this df and am trying to copy or move the b,c to new columns in row one.
I've tried `pivot_table`, `pd.groupby`, and `for index, row in top.iterrows():`

But there may not always be three rows in the `df`. So if there aren't any rows then don't do anything.

This has been my last attempt. I don't remember exactly what I tried with `.groupby` or `pivot_table`

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df1['col2'+row] = df1['col2'][row]
    top_comb = top_comb.append(top)
```

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col21 | Col22 
 y   |   a  |  x   |  b    |   c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like your output to be a single row, you can do the following:

```
if len(df) > 1:
    new_df = df.col2.loc[1:].to_frame().T.reset_index(drop=True)
    new_df.columns = [f'col2{i+1}' for i in range(len(new_df.columns))]
    pd.concat([df.loc[0, :].to_frame().T, new_df], axis=1)


  col1 col2 col3 col21 col22
0    y    a    x     b     c
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col3'], as_index=False).agg(list)
df = pd.concat([df1, df1.pop('col2').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('col2')], 1)
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. I had to adjust it to the rest of my code a little bit but this was a huge help. Thank you

Comment: No problem. @rakurakur